# What are some real world use cases for state channels?

Tags: state-channels

Are there any state channel implementations being used today, or in development? (Not including payment channels)

I'm interested in practical use cases rather than theoretical examples like playing chess on the blockchain.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://raiden.network should be a few practical use cases on the site as well.